# How do you resize a split window in gnu screen to maximum?

Tags: gnu-screen

While in gnu screen for linux, how do I resize the current window to full screen?

```
<ctrl-a> a :resize max
```

does not work.

Comment: found it. its actually crtl-a Q .. this closes all regions, but doesn't close the screens completely as you can go back them them again by just splitting it. i thought it closes everything, but it doesnt.